# Is it possible to break a line on gist?

Tags: github, markdown, gist

When writing in gist, and using mark down mode, we need to enter a blank line between two lines if we want to break a line (add a new line).

Is it possible to break a line without the need of a space (blank line between them)?

Comment: If you’re talking about Markdown, you add two spaces at the end of a line to get a line break.

Comment: thanks very very much, a searched a lot and didn't find this answer in nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ryan said, in markdown the most conventional way of creating a linebreak is by adding two spaces at the end of a line. Though [GFM](https://github.github.com/gfm) also supports the use of basic HTML blocks, so `<br>` can also be used to create linebreaks, which can be helpful where multiple linebreaks are needed.